# Why am i getting this error message ( #1111 - Invalid use of group function )?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve the TIMEDIFF from the last_call field of  every row, where TIMEDIFF between current row and next row is greather than 10 min!
Can someone please help? Meybe there is a better way of doing this?

My goal is to get the total of all timediff between severall database entrys but only if they are greather than 10 min.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( last_call, '%d' ) AS 'day', 

(
 SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MAX(cl1.last_call), MIN(cl1.last_call)))
 FROM calls AS cl1
 WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MAX(cl1.last_call), MIN(cl1.last_call))) > 600
  AND cl1.calling_agent=9
  AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM cl1.last_call ) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM calls.last_call )
) AS 'brake' 


FROM calls
WHERE calling_agent =9
 AND last_call > DATE_SUB( now( ) , INTERVAL 12 MONTH )
GROUP BY EXTRACT( DAY FROM last_call )
```

Comment: try `group by day(last_call)` instead

Comment: `GROUP BY day` group by can see aliases

Comment: Instead of your group by

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? The "timediff of every row", regarding the single field last_call would be always 0.

Comment: provide full error message and mark which part of the query fails.

Comment: The query without this part works: **TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MAX(cl1.last_call), MIN(cl1.last_call))) > 600** The Error is: #1111 - Invalid use of group function